# SendGrid - Whitelist Environments

Tags: block, sendgrid, environment, whitelist

Currently we're using sendgrid in our production, dev and test environments.

Is it possible to have sendgrid only allow emails to be sent to users on a whitelist?

The use case is we have real user email addresses in our dev env and we dont want to accidently have them receive emails. Is it possible to block everything except our dev email addresses?

Comment: I havent seen anything like that on sendgrid however they do have a whitelist for IP addresses so you can maybe only whitelist the production environments IP address. Another option is to handle it in your code - I have a single class function that calls the send email function and if the environment is not production i just skip the sending.